# ¿Por qué el mayor valor a la menor var y viceversa?

Tags: c#, variables

Tengo que hacer un pequeño programa que me devuelva el mayor y menor valor de un grupo de numeros.

La cuestión es que cuando tengo que inicializar las variables sucede que a la variable del mayor valor le adjunto el menor valor posible y a la var del menor valor es al revés, el mayor numero posible, ¿por qué sucede esto? ¿no tendria que ser teóricamente al revés?

Adjunto un pequeño programita en c#:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int numMayor = int.MinValue;
            int numMenor = int.MaxValue;
            int num = 0; int datos = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Cuantos datos quieres ingresar: ");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out datos);

            for (int i = 0; i <datos; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un dato: ");

                num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (num < numMenor)
                {
                    numMenor = num;
                }
                else if (num > numMayor)
                {
                    numMayor = num;

                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("El numero mayor es "+numMayor);
            Console.WriteLine("El numero menor es: "+numMenor);



        }
    }
```

Comment: Coge papel y lapiz y depura a mano tu codigo, lo entenderas muy rapido

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar el depurador de Visual Studio para que te ayude a comprender que pasa por las variables.

Este error se debe a que el `else if` únicamente se ejecuta si no se ha ejecutado el `if` anterior. Si por ejemplo, de entrada ponemos 15, 10 y 5, en este orden de mayor a menor, como todos son menores que el anterior nunca entrará en el número mayor y como tiene por defecto que coja `int.Minvalue` se quedará con dicho valor.

Con cambiar el `else if` por otro `if` te solucionaría ese problema.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int numMayor = int.MinValue;
            int numMenor = int.MaxValue;
            int num = 0; int datos = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Cuantos datos quieres ingresar: ");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out datos);

            for (int i = 0; i <datos; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un dato: ");

                num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (num < numMenor)
                {
                    numMenor = num;
                }
                if (num > numMayor)
                {
                    numMayor = num;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("El numero mayor es "+numMayor);
            Console.WriteLine("El numero menor es: "+numMenor);

        }
    }
```